# Nao permitir data Retroativa no campo tipo Date

Tags: javascript, data

O campo do tipo date não pode permitir datas Retroativas. preciso que o script reconheça a data atual e não permita datas anteriores.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="ultimoDiaTrab" class="control-label">Último dia a ser trabalhado:</label>
    <input type="date" id="ultimoDiaTrab" name="ultimoDiaTrab" class="form-control" disabled />                         
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('ultimoDiaTrab');
input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var agora = new Date();
  var escolhida = new Date(this.value);
  if (escolhida < agora) this.value = [agora.getFullYear(), agora.getMonth() + 1, agora.getDate()].map(v => v < 10 ? '0' + v : v).join('-');
});
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <label for="ultimoDiaTrab" class="control-label">Último dia a ser trabalhado:</label>
  <input type="date" id="ultimoDiaTrab" name="ultimoDiaTrab" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Neste caso `this.value = [agora.getFullYear(), agora.getMonth() + 1, agora.getDate()].map(v => v < 10 ? '0' + v : v).join('-');` repoõe a data escolhida com a data atual, se quiseres somente apagar podes fazer this.value = '';

Comment: Dessa forma, ele Fixa a data atual. Eu preciso que ele reconheça a data atual e não permita datas antigas. ou seja, pode sim ter datas futuras. No caso que me passou, ele não permite. Obrigada, Sergio!!

Comment: @KarinaPinheiro o meu exemplo permite datas futuras.

Comment: Sergio, Funcionou sim! Era um erro meu aqui. Uma pergunta, e se fosse para aparecer um alerte em vez de substituir a data? do tipo " informe uma data Futura" assim que o campo foi preenchido.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui da seguinte maneira

```
    <input type="date" max={new Date().getFullYear() + '-' + String(new Date().getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + new Date().getDate()} name="stockDate" id="dateMax" />
```

Usando a propriedade max, vc consegue estabelecer o maior valor, e através das funções, você consegue pegar a data atual

obs: esse código funciona em react native, talvez tenha que fazer alguma alteração se for html.